# How to handle multiple URLs in beautifultsoup and convert the data into dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, beautifulsoup

I have the list of the URL which i want to use to fetch the data. I can do for one url like this:

```
URL list = ['https://www2.daad.de/deutschland/studienangebote/international-programmes/en/detail/4722/',
'https://www2.daad.de/deutschland/studienangebote/international-programmes/en/detail/6318/'


from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://www2.daad.de/deutschland/studienangebote/international-programmes/en/detail/4479/"
page = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser")

info = soup.find_all("dl", {'class':'c-description-list c-description-list--striped'})

comp_info = pd.DataFrame()
cleaned_id_text = []
for i in info[0].find_all('dt'):
    cleaned_id_text.append(i.text)
cleaned_id__attrb_text = []
for i in info[0].find_all('dd'):
    cleaned_id__attrb_text.append(i.text)


df = pd.DataFrame([cleaned_id__attrb_text], column = cleaned_id_text)
```

But i am not sure how to do this for several urls and append the data into dataframe. Each URL describe the course decription so i want to create the dataframe which will include all the data from the all URL's... And would be nice if i can able to add URL also as separate column in dataframe.

Comment: you've shared only one url. and you haven't shared your expected output

Comment: Thanks. I edited the question by adding the list of urls. I just want t append the data of each url in the df

Comment: Can you be more specific about what the issue is? Do you know how to use loops?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd


numbers = [4722, 6318]


def Main(url):
    with requests.Session() as req:
        for num in numbers:
            r = req.get(url.format(num))
            soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
            target = soup.find(
                "dl", class_="c-description-list c-description-list--striped")
            names = [item.text for item in target.findAll("dt")]
            data = [item.get_text(strip=True) for item in target.findAll("dd")]
            df = pd.DataFrame([data], columns=names)
            df.to_csv("data.csv", index=False, mode="a")


Main("https://www2.daad.de/deutschland/studienangebote/international-programmes/en/detail/{}/")
```

Updated per user-request:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd


def Main(urls):
    with requests.Session() as req:
        allin = []
        for url in urls:
            r = req.get(url)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
            target = soup.find(
                "dl", class_="c-description-list c-description-list--striped")
            names = [item.text for item in target.findAll("dt")]
            names.append("url")
            data = [item.get_text(strip=True) for item in target.findAll("dd")]
            data.append(url)
            allin.append(data)
        df = pd.DataFrame(allin, columns=names)
        df.to_csv("data.csv", index=False)


urls = ['https://www2.daad.de/deutschland/studienangebote/international-programmes/en/detail/4722/',
        'https://www2.daad.de/deutschland/studienangebote/international-programmes/en/detail/6318/']
Main(urls)
```

Comment: Thanks @αԋɱҽԃ αмєяιcαη but i have about 2500 url list and its not easy to get the numbers from each list because some urls have a bit different format.

Comment: well in this case don't use `f-string`, just pass it as list of `urls`. let me update the code. hold on

Comment: Thanks @αԋɱҽԃ αмєяιcαη that works :) but there is a problem that all the name of columns are repeating in each loop. Moreover, is there any possibility to add URL also in a dataframe in a separate column?

Comment: @s_khan92 url column is updated, check updated code. regarding the column names, do you want it to present one time only ?

Comment: Yes because that should be just the name of column in dataframe.

Comment: Exactly what i wanted. Thanks alot :)

Comment: dear s_khan92 and dear αԋɱҽԃ αмєяιcαη - here Zero, the learner in all Python-things who loves your approach.  on a freshly installed ATOM on MX-Linux: i have to setup a lot. for some test i run the code - taken from here: 
see what i have got back *bs4_request_10*  Link:  https://pastebin.com/C3V8vryr
i guess that i set up the machine /ATOM badly … - any and all help greatly appreciated. - regards Zero

Comment: by the way: see more errors: gathered with bs4 scripts form SO within the last 5 days - runned here:
bs4_request_1  Link:  https://pastebin.com/sUmva6iJ   
bs4_request_2  Link:  https://pastebin.com/Tt3XaG4p  
bs4_request_3  Link:  https://pastebin.com/wf9VTvjs  
bs4_request_4  Link:  https://pastebin.com/1s6LVqni  
bs4_request_6  Link:  https://pastebin.com/tEsZxxEs  
bs4_request_7  Link:  https://pastebin.com/55q4ewrq  
bs4_request_8  Link:  https://pastebin.com/YNKAMUXH  
hmm - i guess that i set up the machine /ATOM badly … - any and all help greatly appreciated. - regards Zero

Comment: @zero you have `UnicodeEncodeError`, seems that your system default encoding isn't `utf-8`, therefor, try with `df.to_csv("data.csv", index=False, encoding="utf-8")`

Comment: hi  αԋɱҽԃ αмєяιcαη many many thanks:  you were right - i get back this result in the ATOM -.. 
 
`[Finished in 5.461s]`   
but there remain two little questions:   

a. how ot set the default encoding in ATOM !?   
b. how - and where set the paths in ATOM - note at the moment i do not know where the output is stored !?   

 i look forward to hear from you again . have a great day . .. greetings zero

Comment: @zero [1](https://atom.io/packages/default-encoding) and [2](https://youtu.be/5lsAoQ8lF4M?t=174)